# Question about retrieving JobParameters and retrieving variables from StepExecutionContext in Spring batch 5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, junit5

> I am trying to test my writer and reader that I created with
> Springbatch 5.0. I noticed that when I add
> @Value("#{jobParameters['filename']}" to my writer or even my
> processor, I get this error message, "No Scope registered for scope
> name 'step'". However, if I removed it, it works. Not sure this has
> anything to do with Springbatch 5 changes so bringing it here for help.
>
> Here is what I have:
>
> application-test.properties

```
outputLocation=src/test/resources/output
inputLocation=src/test/resources/input
inputFileName=employee.txt
outputFileName=employees.csv
```

> EmployeeRecord.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeRecord implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;
    private String salary;
    private LocalDateTime joiningDate;
    private String fileName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", EmployeeRecord.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("employeeNumber='" + employeeNumber + "'")
                .add("firstName='" + firstName + "'")
                .add("lastName='" + lastName + "'")
                .add("role='" + role + "'")
                .add("salary='" + salary + "'")
                .add("joiningDate=" + joiningDate + "'")
                .add("fileName=" + fileName)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

> Employee.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;
    private String salary;
    private LocalDateTime joiningDate;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Employee.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("employeeNumber='" + employeeNumber + "'")
                .add("firstName='" + firstName + "'")
                .add("lastName='" + lastName + "'")
                .add("role='" + role + "'")
                .add("salary='" + salary + "'")
                .add("joiningDate=" + joiningDate)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

> ReaderWriter.java

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ReaderWriter {
    @Value("${inputLocation}")
    private String inputLocation;
    @Value("${outputLocation}")
    private String outputLocation;
    @Value("${inputFileName}")
    private String inputFileName;
    @Value("${outputFileName}")
    private String outputFileName;
    @Autowired
    private FieldSetMapper<Employee> employeeFieldSetMapper;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader() {
        log.info("reading from -> {} ", inputLocation);
        log.debug("reading from -> {} ", inputLocation);
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("employeeItemReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(inputLocation+"/"+inputFileName))
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .fieldSetMapper(employeeFieldSetMapper)
                .lineMapper(lineMapper())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<EmployeeRecord> flatFileItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['filename']}") String fileName) throws MalformedURLException {
        log.info("writing to -> {} ", outputLocation);
        String file = outputLocation+"/"+outputFileName;
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<EmployeeRecord>()
                .name("employeeItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(file))
                .lineAggregator(lineAggregator())
                .headerCallback(header -> header.write(fileName))
                .build();
    }

    private DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer());
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(employeeFieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    private LineTokenizer tokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames("id", "employeeNumber", "firstName", "lastName", "role", "salary", "joiningDate");
        return delimitedLineTokenizer;
    }

    private LineAggregator<EmployeeRecord> lineAggregator() {
        DelimitedLineAggregator<EmployeeRecord> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(extractor());
        return delimitedLineAggregator;
    }

    private FieldExtractor<EmployeeRecord> extractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<EmployeeRecord> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{
                "id",
                "employeeNumber",
                "firstName",
                "lastName",
                "role",
                "salary",
                "joiningDate",
                "fileName"
        });
        beanWrapperFieldExtractor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return beanWrapperFieldExtractor;
    }

}
```

> EmployeeProcessor.java

```
@StepScope
@Slf4j
@Component("employeeProcessor")
public class EmployeeProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Employee, EmployeeRecord> {
    @Value("#{jobParameters['filename']}")
    private String fileName;

    @Override
    public EmployeeRecord process(Employee employee) throws Exception {
        Long id = employee.getId();
        String employeeNumber = employee.getEmployeeNumber();
        String firstName = employee.getFirstName();
        String lastName = employee.getLastName();
        String role = employee.getRole();
        String salary = employee.getSalary();
        LocalDateTime joiningDate = employee.getJoiningDate();

        EmployeeRecord employeeProcessed = new EmployeeRecord();
        employeeProcessed.setId(id);
        employeeProcessed.setFirstName(firstName);
        employeeProcessed.setLastName(lastName);
        employeeProcessed.setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);
        employeeProcessed.setSalary(salary);
        employeeProcessed.setJoiningDate(joiningDate);
        employeeProcessed.setFileName(fileName);
        employeeProcessed.setRole(role);
        return employeeProcessed;
    }
}
```

> EmployeeStepListener.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component("employeeStepListener")
public class EmployeeStepListener implements StepExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        log.info("Called beforeStep -> {} ", stepExecution.getJobParameters().getString("filename"));
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        log.info("Called afterStep");
        return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
    }
}
```

> BatchConfig.java

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job employeeJob(JobRepository jobRepository,@Qualifier("employeeStep") Step employeeStep,@Qualifier("employeeJobListener") JobExecutionListener listener) {
        log.debug("inside employeeJob");
        return new JobBuilder("employeeJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(employeeStep)
                .build();
    }

}
```

> EmployeeFieldSetMapper.java

```
@Component("employeeFieldSetMapper")
public class EmployeeFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Employee> {

    @Override
    public Employee mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(fieldSet.readLong("id"));
        employee.setFirstName(fieldSet.readString("firstName"));
        employee.setLastName(fieldSet.readString("lastName"));
        employee.setRole(fieldSet.readString("role"));
        employee.setSalary(fieldSet.readString("salary"));
        String dateTime = fieldSet.readString("joiningDate");
        employee.setJoiningDate(LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime,dateTimeFormatter));

        return employee;
    }
}
```

> EmployeeCommonConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class EmployeeCommonConfig {
    @Qualifier("batchDataSource")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    protected JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource));
        factory.setIncrementerFactory(new DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(dataSource));
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreateEnum(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED);
        factory.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    protected JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher launcher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
        launcher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
        launcher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return launcher;
    }
}
```

> StepConfig.java

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class StepConfig {
    @Value("${inputLocation}")
    private String inputLocation;
    @Value("${outputLocation}")
    private String outputLocation;
    @Value("${inputFileName}")
    private String inputFileName;
    @Value("${outputFileName}")
    private String outputFileName;
    @Autowired
    private ItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader;
    @Autowired
    private ItemWriter<EmployeeRecord> flatFileItemWriter;
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeProcessor employeeProcessor;


    @Bean
    public Step employeeStep(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        log.debug("debug: in employeeStep");
        log.info("info: in employeeStep");
        log.debug("inputLocation -> {} ", inputLocation);
        log.debug("outputLocation -> {} ", outputLocation);
        return new StepBuilder("employeeStep",jobRepository)
                .<Employee,EmployeeRecord>chunk(2,transactionManager)
                .reader(flatFileItemReader)
                .processor(employeeProcessor)
                .writer(flatFileItemWriter)
                .listener("employeeStepListener")
                .build();
    }

}
```

> DbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean("batchDataSource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

}
```

> DatabaseTestConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseTestConfig {

    @Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "batchTransactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager batchTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(batchDataSource());
    }
}
```

> EmployeeTestConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"},
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan .Filter (type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {BatchConfig.class})})
public class EmployeeTestConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Bean
    public Job employeeJob(@Qualifier("employeeStep") Step employeeStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("employeeJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(employeeStep)
                .build();
    }
}
```

> EmployeeExecutionTest.java

```
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig({EmployeeTestConfig.class, DatabaseTestConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:data-h2.sql")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class EmployeeExecutionTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Test
    public void employeeJobExecutionTest() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameter = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("filename", "testname").toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameter);
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

    }
}
```

> Stacktrace:
>
> 2023.03.22 20:41:29.930 [INFO] org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler: Executing step:
> [employeeStep]
> 2023.03.22 20:41:29.937 [ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep: Encountered an error
> executing step employeeStep in job employeeJob
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name
> 'step'
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
> at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:686)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
> at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$$SpringCGLIB$$0.open()
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:124)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:293)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:224)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:417)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:132)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:316)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
> ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:148)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:70)
> ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:146)
> ~[spring-batch-test-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
> at com.codi.springbatch.springbatchapp.EmployeeExecutionTest.employeeJobExecutionTest(EmployeeExecutionTest.java:27)
> ~[test-classes/:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[?:?]
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
> ~[junit-platform-commons-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
> ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
> ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> 2023.03.22 20:41:29.948 [INFO] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep: Step: [employeeStep]
> executed in 16ms
> 2023.03.22 20:41:29.952 [ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep: Exception while
> closing step execution resources in step employeeStep in job
> employeeJob java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for
> scope name 'step'

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the error or a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help you efficiently. There are 4 variations of what you are describing and it is not easy to understand what you are expecting.

Comment: I updated the code with as much information as possible, hopefully this is enough @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: I have essentially provided the complete sample code as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue based on the code you shared (BTW, you did add imports and did not share pom.xml or gradle.build, this should be part of the minimal example, otherwise people won't be able to run your sample). Anyway, I shared an example with a step-scoped item writer and a complete test. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Spring Batch 5. I could not run your sample and reproduce the issue, but the error means that a step-scoped component is invoked outside the scope of a step (ie not while the step is running).

Another note about the code you shared. I see that you are adding the attribute `TOTAL_RECORDS` in the step execution context after the step (ie in method `StepExecutionListener#afterStep`), but reading it in the item writer bean definition writer `@Value("#stepExecutionContext['TOTAL_RECORDS']}") long recordCount`. This is not correct as the item writer is invoked before the listener's `afterStep` method.

**EDIT: I could not reproduce the issue with the shared code. Here is a minimal complete verifiable example:**

File `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so75784914</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so75784914</name>
    <description>Demo project for SO 75784914</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

File `src/main/java/com/example/so75784914/JobConfig.java`

```
package com.example.so75784914;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {

    @Bean
    public ListItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        List<Person> items = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(1, "foo1")
                , new Person(2, "foo2")
                , new Person(3, "bar1")
                , new Person(4, "bar2")
        );
        return new ListItemReader<>(items);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> itemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(fileName))
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager,
                     ItemReader<Person> reader, ItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<Person, Person>chunk(2, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JobConfig.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("fileName", "persons.csv")
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }

    public static class Person {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public Person() {
        }

        public Person(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Person{id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

File `src/test/java/com/example/so75784914/So75784914ApplicationTests.java`

```
package com.example.so75784914;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig({JobConfig.class})

class So75784914ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void employeeJobExecutionTest() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameter = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("fileName", "output.csv")
                .toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameter);
        Assertions.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

    }

}
```

---

This example uses a step-scoped item writer where the output file name is configured from job parameters. When I run the test, the output file is written correctly without any issue. The sample uses Spring Batch version 5.0.1 as in the question.

Comment: What I have noticed is that, “no scope registered for scope named step” is a generic message which hides underlying issues. As I was able to test different scenarios with and without the injection leaves me to believe this is related to Springbatch 5 and JUnit 5 unless I can see a working code to tell me otherwise.

Comment: I looked at the open issues in spring batch github project, I see a few issues related to StepScope. I think this issue is due to the transaction being closed before the bean annotated with StepScope is used. To me, it seems the annotation is causing Spring to close the transaction before the bean containing the StepScope annotation is started.

Comment: This is not related to transactions, it could happen even in a non transactional step. You did not provide a minimal complete verifiable example, so it is inefficient to try to guess what your issue actually is.

Comment: I have essentially provided the complete sample code as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue based on the code you shared (BTW, you did add imports and did not share pom.xml or gradle.build, this should be part of the minimal example, otherwise people won't be able to run your sample). Anyway, I shared an example with a step-scoped item writer and a complete test. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also per documentation, it seems using the EnableBatchProcessing annotation causes auto-configuration to back off so not sure why it is being used.  The documentation for spring batch 5.0 needs work imo

Comment: You are using a job launcher to run the job. Why do I have to do this? Running it on the command line would not work

Comment: You did not mention using spring boot in the question. Hence, I provided a sample with only spring batch. `You are using a job launcher to run the job. Why do I have to do this? `: you can remove that `main` method if you want (I added it just to run the app outside a unit test), your question is about the testing part, which works as expected without the issue your mentioned.

Comment: Adding @EnableBatchProcessing solved the issue. From Springbatch 5.0, the doc says the EnableBatchProcessing annotation is no longer required and its effect causes Spring boot's auto configuration to back off completely giving you full control of spring batch. However, the downside of removing it is that StepScope annotation is no longer recognized (not sure if this is the exact term), but in my case, chunk processing fails to close on completion. Seems as of now, using the annotation is still required even in Spring boot 3 unless you want to use custom code.